# fb_social vs service_links

Tags: social-network

I'm trying to add a facebook like button to my website. I've tried `fb_social` which seems to do the job, however, it seems that `Service Links` can do it as well, but I couldn't figure it out.

As I haven't been able to make `Service Links` work, maybe I am mistaken and it doesn't do what I think it does.

I'm thinking of Service Links over Facebook social because in the future I'll propably add more service than just facebook.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Straight-up module comparisons aren't really suited to this format (what are you trying to compare exactly?), but if you have a specific question about what one can/can't do, or about how to set it up, that would be

Comment: Yes, can I display a facebook like button, using servic links, and if so, how